# Websocket not send message until client is disconnected

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ratchet

I'm learning WebSocket using PHP library Ratchet. But I have a problem sending the message from client/browser. I have tried using chrome and firefox.

The message is not sent to the server until I disconnect the client by closing the tab or refresh the browser.

Update: My server use Centos 7 with firewalld enabled.

After I close the browser tab, the server output is like this:

```
Connection 73 sending message "tes" to 1 other connection
Connection 73 has disconnected
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
conn = new WebSocket('ws://websocket.develop.local:8080');
            conn.onopen = function(e) {
                console.log("Connection established!");
            };

            conn.onmessage = function(e) {
                console.log('ada message');
                console.log(e.data);
            };
            conn.onerror = function(e) {
               console.log("WebSocket Error: " , e);
               //Custom function for handling errors
               //handleErrors(e);
            };
            function sendMessage(){
                    var message = document.getElementById("pesan").value;
                    conn.send(message);
                    console.log('Sending message: ' + message);
            };
```

And here is the PHP code (I got this from Ratchet docs):

```
    <?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you call the sendMessage function ?

Comment: From my local computer (windows 10). The websocket (websocket.develop.local) is running on virtual box using Centos 7.

Comment: In the piece of code you have sent there are no place where you explicitly call the sendMessage function...  Are there ?

Comment: I call it from console. Using chrome browser.